# Decomposition of Sugar Temperature

Tags: decomposition

I am perplexed by information on the internet about the sugar raffinose.

The melting point of raffinose is 244.4°F
The boiling point of raffinose is 1,623°F

I can't find the temperature at which it will break apart into it's constituent sugars.

The boiling point seems too high to me tbh, because it should be on fire at that point.

Is it that raffinose decomposes at it's meting point?

Comment: The boiling point is nonsense, of course. It will break apart long before that.

Comment: Do you know what temperature it will break at Ivan?

Comment: No. Or at least not precisely, so to put it. Someplace between 100 °C and 300 °C, I guess.